# Vertically center RibbonComboBox in RibbonGroup (in WPF)

Tags: wpf, vertical-alignment, ribbon-control

I would like know whether there is a possibility to vertically center a RibbonComboBox in a RibbonGroup without setting a margin.
I tried to use VerticalAlignment and VerticalContentAlignment, but unfortunately this did not work.

This is how it looks right now:

[image: Right now]

This is how it should look like (please without using margin-settings):

[image: required]

This is my code at the moment:

```
<RibbonTab Name="RibbonTab_Test" Header="Test">
   <RibbonGroup Name="RibbonGroup_Test" Header="New Test">
       <RibbonComboBox Name="RibbonComboBox_Test" IsEditable="False" SmallImageSource="img/verschreibungspflichtige-pillendose-16.png">
           <RibbonGallery SelectedValue="This Test-Text is to long" SelectedValuePath="Content" MaxColumnCount="1">
               <RibbonGalleryCategory>
                  <RibbonGalleryItem Content="This Test-Text is to long"/>
                  <RibbonGalleryItem Content="Test 1"/>
                  <RibbonGalleryItem Content="Test 2"/>
               </RibbonGalleryCategory>
            </RibbonGallery>
        </RibbonComboBox>
    </RibbonGroup>
</RibbonTab>
```

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to achieve this is by adding a grid with a very big height and setting vertical alignment to center:

```
<RibbonGroup Name="RibbonGroup_Test" Header="New Test">
    <Grid VerticalAlignment="Center" MinHeight="120">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RibbonComboBox Name="RibbonComboBox_Test" IsEditable="False" VerticalAlignment="Center" SmallImageSource="img/verschreibungspflichtige-pillendose-16.png">
            <RibbonGallery SelectedValue="This Test-Text is to long" SelectedValuePath="Content" MaxColumnCount="1" >
                <RibbonGalleryCategory>
                    <RibbonGalleryItem Content="This Test-Text is to long"/>
                    <RibbonGalleryItem Content="Test 1"/>
                    <RibbonGalleryItem Content="Test 2"/>
                </RibbonGalleryCategory>
            </RibbonGallery>
        </RibbonComboBox>
    </Grid>
</RibbonGroup>
```

[image: Vertical aligned ribbon]

Comment: I already tried to upvote your answer, but the system say (at the moment) that I do not have enough reputation. But I will try it again, as soon as my reputation-level is high enough.